# Android application using libgdx crashes since update to ADT 17

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

My Android program crashes. This started after updating Eclipse to 3.6.2 and updating the SDK and ADT (to 17), I had a problem. (After I updated eclipse, my ddms crashed too, but i fixed that.) I've now updated my SDK and ADT to 18, but I still have this problem. My lib folders in my Java project and Android project haven't changed. I use Mario tutorials and build those. My java project runs well, but I don't understand why my Android projects cant run.

Crash screenshot in my phone:
[image]

LogCat in Eclipse:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it's been explained and solved [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2362), some change of the latest ADT plugin causes this, solution is just add all the needed sources to your Android project, as the link says.

Comment: that was a good point to remind me. but i don't know why, i still have this problem. it's strange.

Comment: so... it seems my problem was somewhere else. :D 
now i can run my projects. thanks.