# Updated eclipse, adt, Libgdx doesn't compile on android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I'm currently using libgdx for game I'm writing, and I just continued writing this game from around 2 months ago, so I started up eclipse, updated everything ( took a while ) and then proceeded to program on the pc, fixing some bugs and adding stuff. Later I tried to run it on my android (Galaxy Nexus) but I got an error:

```
04-24 09:51:57.620: E/dalvikvm(19561): Could not find class 'com.thundergodpc.ThunderGod', referenced from method com.thundergodandroid.ThunderGodActivity.onCreate
04-24 09:51:57.620: W/dalvikvm(19561): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 616 (Lcom/thundergodpc/ThunderGod;) in Lcom/thundergodandroid/ThunderGodActivity;
04-24 09:51:57.620: D/dalvikvm(19561): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0003
04-24 09:51:57.620: D/dalvikvm(19561): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x19b2 at 0x05 in Lcom/thundergodandroid/ThunderGodActivity;.onCreate
04-24 09:51:57.620: D/dalvikvm(19561): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.thundergod/lib/libgdx.so 0x41817918
04-24 09:51:57.628: D/dalvikvm(19561): Added shared lib /data/data/com.thundergod/lib/libgdx.so 0x41817918
04-24 09:51:57.628: D/dalvikvm(19561): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.thundergod/lib/libgdx.so 0x41817918, skipping init
04-24 09:51:57.628: D/AndroidRuntime(19561): Shutting down VM
04-24 09:51:57.628: W/dalvikvm(19561): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a5a1f8)
04-24 09:51:57.698: E/AndroidRuntime(19561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 09:51:57.698: E/AndroidRuntime(19561): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.thundergodpc.ThunderGod
```

I thought maybe I'm using 1.7 on the desktop but I'm using 1.6 JDK compliance on it so it should not be a problem. I was getting a bit frustrated so I tried following the basic installation tutorial again, but I got the same error. So finally I thought of posting here, could anyone shed some light on how to fix this?

Comment: maybe it has to do with your project configuration ? it seems that libgdx isn't correctly linked or something. Have you perform some checks on Java Build paths? or even redo the tutorial steps for configuring the project, if that's how you did start it.

Comment: @BiAiB Well it links, and does see the files, otherwise it would not compile. I've already tried following the tutorial steps, I'm getting the same error. But yes, I also think it's probably a configuration error, But I'm not really sure where because it worked before the updates. I'm like the error says, It probably has something to do with not being able to read the jar, because it does see the files... hmm

Comment: well anyway I don't think it's a compile error at that point because eclipse would have failed way before you can send the apk to the device. Maybe you could ask the folks at libgdx forum. Good luck.

Comment: btw, there's reports on projects broken with adt update, here: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2362 maybe it's related

Comment: @BiAiB that was the answer! if you post an answer I could give you points for it!

Comment: Well, that was just some clues, I didn't build an answer. Thank you anyway, have a happy coding and may I see your game soon on the market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think i know your answer. you can't run your android project but your java project run well.(if i understand it well). look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165471/android-application-using-libgdx-crashes-since-update-to-adt-17/10166416#10166416).

anyway, i had this problem too. i say it to you cuz i solve this problem on my own. if your DDMS won't work, you can just copy the old adb.exe to your new update. (if you have this problem)

maybe after do this works, you still can't run your projects. so you must [download](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2381) latest library of libgx and replace them to old one. java libs and android libs. then you can run them.